# Does PHP CLI on macOS and Linux using the built-in Web server behave like it does on Windows for executing commands?

Tags: php, linux, macos, command-line

This is working on my Windows 10 system, but I'm very skeptical as to whether it will also work on Linux and macOS. I want to ensure that it does, because it's incredibly useful to be able to run commands to open various applications from the localhost "web control panel". I do it all the time, but don't have a Mac or a Linux PC for testing.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Make sure that you're running the built-in PHP webserver and not something else.
2. Create a file called `test.php` with this content and put it in your WWW root:

   ```
    if (isset($_GET['run']))
        shell_exec('winver');

    echo '<p><a href="?run=1">test me</a></p>';
   ```

Obviously change the "winver" part to a command that macOS or Linux will understand. As long as it brings up some kind of GUI window when run.

3. Go to `http://127.0.0.1/test.php` and click the hyperlink.
4. It should now run the specified command and thus display a GUI box of some kind on the screen.

Does this happen on macOS and Linux, or is this a "lucky coincidence" that just happens to work on Windows but wasn't intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested this and successfully launched *Microsoft Word* on macOS and *xcalc* on Linux.

You do have to be careful that the user the web server is running has has access to the desktop (e.g. in Linux you need to have `DISPLAY` set correctly etc) but that isn't an issue if you are using `php -S` on the same desktop you want to display the GUI application on.

Comment: please write the script to open `TextEdit` on Mac and will it be executable from a remote link if hosted in server

Comment: @Chilarai — It's the same as the script in the question except the path will be to the TextEdit binary. And yes, it will be executable from a remote link. (For some value of "server" equal to the description of how to set up the test case using `php -S`) given in the question)